# LINQ DefaultIfEmpty(), generating inferred argument error

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to get the below linq query to return `-1` if there isn't any current value.  I was looking at this article on MSDN, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx), and it seemed that `DefaultIfEmpty()` was what I wanted.

Unfortunately, I am getting a `The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage.  Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` error.

I guess I am not sure what that means or what it is telling me to do.  Can someone explain, please.

```
 public static int CheckForDRIID(int personID)
    {
        using (var context = ConnectDataContext.Create())
        {
            var masterIndex =
                (from applicationAssociation in context.tblApplicationAssociations
                 where applicationAssociation.ApplicationID == 1 && applicationAssociation.PersonID == personID
                 select applicationAssociation.PersonApplicationID).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Single();


            return Convert.ToInt32(masterIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what type is `applicationAssociation.PersonApplicationID`? is it an `int` or a `Nullable<int>`?

Comment: `PersonApplicationID` is a `string`

Comment: Why the heck are you storing an ID in a string? Bad database design that you cannot change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-1 is an int and `applicationAssociation.PersionApplicationID` isn't, so it doesn't know what to return.  You could replace -1 with the same type as `applicationAssociation.PersionApplicationID`, "-1".  Or specify the type like `DefaultIfEmpty<string>`.  And a third options is to do the `Convert.ToInt32` in the select.

Answer (score 1):

That code works fine for me:

```
public static int CheckForDRIID(int personID)
{
    var someAssociaction = new { ApplicationID = 1, PersonID = 1, PersonApplicationID = 1 };
    var associactions = (new[] { someAssociaction }).ToList();
    associactions.Add(new { ApplicationID = 2, PersonID = 2, PersonApplicationID = 2 });

    int masterIndex =
        (from applicationAssociation in associactions
         where applicationAssociation.ApplicationID == 1 && applicationAssociation.PersonID == personID
         select applicationAssociation.PersonApplicationID).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Single();

    return masterIndex;
}
```

I just created a sample set of associactions, because I dont have your datacontext. By the way: you can just declare `masterIndex` an `int`, because you know the type the expression will return, so you dont need a `var`.

So the cause for your problem lies somewhere else: the `PersonApplicationID` field is not an `int`, therefore the compiler does not know which type it should infer for the generic function `DefaultIfEmpty`.

**Update:**
Just tried the above example with setting the `PersonApplicationID` property to:

- `new Nullable<int>(1)`: Throws *"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'"*
- `1f`: Throws *"Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'"*
- `""`: Throws *"The type arguments for method `DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."*

So, I assume you are storing strings in your database's `PersonApplicationID` field. If so, either change your database, or parse the string to an int in the Linq query:

```
public static int CheckForDRIID(int personID)
{
    using (var context = ConnectDataContext.Create())
    {
        int masterIndex =
            (from applicationAssociation in context.tblApplicationAssociations
             where applicationAssociation.ApplicationID == 1 && applicationAssociation.PersonID == personID
             select int.Parse(applicationAssociation.PersonApplicationID)).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Single();

        return masterIndex;
    }
}
```